# Remove factors from boxplot that have no data

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two factors: Peel - either "Standard" or "Delay" and Wafer - a number of a wafer but which I want as a factor:

```
**Peel**       **Wafer**   
Standard          122     
Standard          123     
Delay             124     
Delay             125
```

(sorry I am trying to post real data but it seems to come out in a dodgy format)

When I boxplot my data for a variable against both factors, I get gaps on the x axis where there is no data:

```
boxplot(Von.fwd~Wafer*Peel, data=df, las=2)
```

I have tried posting an image but apparently I need 10 reputation to do this.

The data is missing because it doesn't exist. I just dont want it to plot the gap. I have looked at the `droplevel` code but I dont want to drop either of my factors, just certain combinations of the factors.

Is there a way to tell R not to plot crossed factors where there is no data?

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: Where is `Von.fwd` coming from?

Comment: It is a measurement I make for each Wafer (roughly 2000 points per Wafer). So it is all in a data frame together.

Comment: Right, but can you include that as well so your example is reproducible?

Comment: Sorry, I will try again.

Comment: Im just reading up on how to post data properly...the edit above is a mess im sorry for that.

Comment: ah thank you for formatting beginneR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to combine `Peel` and `Wafer` into a new factor like so (assuming your `data.frame` is called `df`):

### Edit

Sorry did not think that through:

```
df$NewFactor<-paste(df$Peel,df$Wafer)  
df$NewFactor<-factor(df$NewFactor)
```

That will give you each combination as a factor, but no missing combinations. Then you can use `df$newFactor` in your `boxplot` function.

Comment: It gave an error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "NewFactor", value = c(3L, 1L, 4L,  : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 5002                               Maybe this is my fault for not showing you the format of the data frame correctly?